# What does ‘to be all in’ mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I encountered the following sentence:

“This was not in fact an original idea, but was based on the English ‘Harvest Festival’, an old custom whereby people gave thanks to God once the crops were all in.”

What does *“once the crops were all in”* mean?

Comment: "All in" in this context means "all harvested (or gathered)"; it may once have suggested "all in the barn" or "all in wagon"—that is, no longer on the growing plants, waiting to be picked or reaped.

Comment: @students007 Keep in mind that "be all in" can also mean that a person is completely invested in an idea, project, plan of action, etc. Looking at the context of the phrase is necessary :)

Comment: Also bear in mind that *I'm all in!* can be used to mean *I'm exhausted!*, same as *I'm [completely] **done in**!*

Comment: You should not be focusing on *all* for this, only on what it means to say that the crops are in. One subtlety may he that it means something different in spring than it does in autumn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, in this context it refers to the crops having been *harvested*. This is exemplified in the well-known [Christian harvest hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come,_Ye_Thankful_People,_Come), where the qualification of ‘in’ makes this clear:

> Come, ye thankful people, come,
>
> Raise the song of harvest home!
>
> *All is safely gathered **in***,
>
> Ere the winter storms begin;
>
> God, our Maker, doth provide
>
> For our wants to be supplied;
>
> Come to God’s own temple, come;
>
> Raise the song of harvest home!

This quotation is from Wikipedia. However the [version](https://www.worshipworkshop.org.uk/songs-and-hymns/hymns/come-ye-thankful-people-come/) I am familiar with from my (English) youth has:

> “All **be** safely gathered in…”

Comment: But of course there are at least a half-dozen other senses of the term "all in".

Comment: @HotLicks — Of course. But the question specially mentions harvest. The title is at fault, not the question or answer. I’ll edit it when I have a moment.